# PostgreSQL percentile_cont return same value for all percentiles

Tags: sql, postgresql, statistics, percentile

I am trying to extract percentiles from some data but I get the same values for each percentile. Why?

```
SELECT three_sixty_review_aid, 
percentile_cont(0.95) within group (order by questions_combined asc) as p_95,
percentile_cont(0.75) within group (order by questions_combined asc) as p_75,
percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by questions_combined asc) as p_50,
percentile_cont(0.25) within group (order by questions_combined asc) as p_25,
percentile_cont(0.1) within group (order by questions_combined asc) as p_10,
percentile_cont(0.05) within group (order by questions_combined asc) as p_05
FROM reviews_threesixty.peer_review_avg_combined_per_review
 group by three_sixty_review_aid
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the other column? Since you are grouping by that value I think you would get all of the distinct values. Also, does Postgres not require an `OVER` clause here? I suppose that could be unique to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, multi-rows should be returned for each row composed of *percentile_cont* columns, if *GROUP BY* used, all *percentile_cont* columns form single rows provided *three_sixty_review_aid* has unique values. Therefore, if three_sixty_review_aid columns have unique values, then remove group by expression to get different values for rows composed of *percentile_cont* columns :

```
SELECT  percentile_cont(0.95) within group (order by questions_combined asc) as p_95,
        percentile_cont(0.75) within group (order by questions_combined asc) as p_75,
        percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by questions_combined asc) as p_50,
        percentile_cont(0.25) within group (order by questions_combined asc) as p_25,
        percentile_cont(0.1) within group (order by questions_combined asc) as p_10,
        percentile_cont(0.05) within group (order by questions_combined asc) as p_05
   FROM reviews_threesixty.peer_review_avg_combined_per_review;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/20017/1)

Comment: Good day, thanks for the reply, it is most appreciated. However I now get the "ERROR: Syntax error at or near limit". Very weird, PostgreSQL 10.4

Comment: @Letholdrus you're welcome, but I can't see a word `limit`.

Comment: @Letholdrus I've added a demo.

Comment: I added the query plan based on your original answer to my top level question

Comment: @Letholdrus Is `three_sixty_review_aid` a uniquely valued column?

Comment: your solution works 100%. I am connecting via a iPhone app to the DB and the app settings must have caused this weird limit business. After I created the view proper and ran it (not as a select) it works 100%. Thanks for taking the time to make the demo as well friend.